# Atom or Rstudio like IDE alternative for julia language

Tags: julia

Similar to Rstudio, Atom allowed you to run code segments on interactively rather than the entire script all at once. Is there a suitable Julia language IDE that is comparable to rstudio or Atom (juno) and allows for on-the-fly execution of code blocks because Atom is being phased out?

note: Thanks for answers in vs code to obtain interactive feature hold ctrl + return will run code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft VS Code you can define code cells using magic comments (`##` or `# %%` or `#-` can play this role - the choice is yours):

```
##

(your code goes here)

##
```

A code cell is executed by pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while the cursor is inside the cell.

At the code below I pressed <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while being in line 10.

[image]

The keyboard shortcut can be configured by selecting in the main menu View->Command Palette or pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: great - thank you - working interactively.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the Microsoft Visual Studio Code ? You can check how to download and setup for Julia notebook in link below.

https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode#installing-juliavs-codevs-code-julia-extension

The Best, Wr

Answer (score 3):

VSCode. The Julia team was working on a Julia IDE called [Juno](https://junolab.org/) but the website now says "Juno will receive no more feature updates. Development focus has shifted to the Julia extension for VSCode", and VSCode seems to be the recommended way to develop in julia.

The Julia extension for VSCode let's you run code block by just pressing `shift+enter` and it uses Revise.jl to make interactive sessions better. You can see plots and other outputs right in the editor, and recenty they have even added performance monitoring/benchmarking tools.

However, if you prefer notebook-style workflows, you can use Jupyter with Julia (and the IJulia kernel) but even better imo is [Pluto](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl), which is specifically made for Julia and has some nice features such as no hidden state.

Comment: Ok the interactive feature I would like to retain. I will give it a try. Also possible to load in functions from another script in same vs code instance?

Comment: If by different script you mean like a different file, then yes. Also you can set each file to be inside a module if you're working on bigger projects so you have the correct functions available in each file. 

In short, most stuff is in VSCode for julia. And if it isn't, I doubt you will find it anywhere else.